# C# read and react to a text string

Tags: c#

assume that there is a string named "message", and assume an user type in the console,

"!My FB List", but words "FB" and "List" could be change. But "!My" won't change. So, I want to save the text the user type. Only if user used "!My" before the other words.

So, I don't know how to get this to 'if' command. Plz help me.

> if (message == "!My "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
if (message.StartsWith("!My "))
{
   // do something
}
```

This code works in most situations. However, if you need to resolve situations like `Kshitij Mehta` mentioned in the comments, you'd be probably better off with a `Split` method parsing the string and comparing the first object of the array to the required string.
When you've split the input string into an array, you will just compare strings in a typical fashion (==), probably no need for fancy methods in that scenario.

One more "however" to consider - if your input string is long, splitting might not be the best idea to do. In that case I'd probably use regular expressions to compare the beginning of the inputted string.

The implementation depends on your needs. Just pick what suits you the best :)

Comment: @KshitijMehta, are we talking about the original answer or the updated one? Because after the update this "issue" seems to be fixed, or at least it's giving me the right result.

Comment: @KshitijMehta, I know what does it mean, I'm just saying this function is giving me the right result = false. In which scenario is your statement true, so I can replicate the issue when it's giving the wrong result? Your string results in `False`....

Comment: you want it to be true, because the first "word" is still "!My", since a tab (or any other whitespace) should be treated as a word-break

Comment: @KshitijMehta, thanks, added a note about that scenario. There are certainly cases when you need to think about such situations as well.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to accept commands and then do specific things based on those commands. Apparently, the "command" is the first word in the text typed by the user.

Thus, I'd [split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) the message at whitespace and then `switch` for the first word:

```
var words = message.Split();
var command = words[0];

switch (command) {
    case "!My":
        // Do something
        ...
        break;

    case "!SomethingElse":
        // Do something else
        ...
        break;
    ...
}
```

Afterwards, you can use `words[1]` to get "FB" and `words[2]` to get "list". Be sure to use `words.Length` to verify if the required number of parameters has been specified before trying to access them.

Answer (score 2):

String class includes many static methods, among which is `StartsWith()`.

so your if statement can simply be

```
 if(UserString.StartsWith("!My"))
 {
      // other conditional code here
 }
```

It is not clear from your question whether you want to include cases where the user types `"!My"` before typing anything else, but he/she does NOT type a space immediately after typing `!My`.
If you only want to process the code if the three characters `"!My"` were followed by a space, then, (as suggested by @Walther),  add a space to the test string in the `StartsWith()` method

```
 if(UserString.StartsWith("!My "))
 {
      // other conditional code here
 }
```

Comment: Your code has the same exact issue as my original answer :)))

Comment: @Walther.  you are right.  And op's example code does include a space  (`if (message == "!My "`)